# ReLU derivative - second order effects

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

I am reading the Deep Learning Book, where there is a section on [generalisations of the ReLU](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/map.html) (section 6.3.1).

It states:

> The second derivative of the rectifying operation is 0 almost everywhere, and the derivative of the rectifying operation is 1 everywhere that the unit is active. This means that the gradient direction is far more useful for learning than it would be with activation functions that introduce second-order eﬀects.

I then read [a short and simple paper](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://papers.nips.cc/paper/1189-second-order-learning-algorithm-with-squared-penalty-term.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwixrJiT-pnSAhWHPBoKHWdlDkgQFggfMAA&usg=AFQjCNH4_2bBJ5vOoQJFwvRbQUjNbtLLug&sig2=eF2SI-75vyENUjjECVmy4A) about second order effects, which confirmed my memories that second order effects can help to optimisation to run more efficiently.

I was then wondering why the book so sweepingly said that the gradient direction of activation functions without second order effects are more useful than those with second order effects?

Is it that the first order gradient (of the ReLU in this case) must therefore encode all gradient information, and so are alone as efficient as can be? The fact that the ReLU's second order derivative is zero of course means that gradient information is stored solely in it's first derivative, given that the second order's zero value doesn't aid gradient descent calculations, as zero terms cannot alter the weights.

Can anybody explain the authors' thoughts here, or perhaps recommend any literature regarding the second order effects of activation functions?

Comment: I was thinking about what "second-order effects" means in that sentence today. In 4.3.1, it seems that the author explains the effects of second-order derivatives being zero, positive and negative on predicting a function by using gradient descent.

Comment: This comes a little late but maybe someone else will find this useful. 
I think it is important to note that the author specifically talks about optimization via gradient descent. Gradient descent only uses first order gradient information. So even though second order information may help with optimization, gradient descent will not utilize it. However, I don't know why it is a good thing that the ReLU function does not introduce second order effects.